# how to create a new page that is not in the hierarchy?

Tags: posts

I want to create a "trending" page that shows posts according to the views, but this page is not in the wordpress theme hierarchy.

I don't know where and how to add, I tried to create one and uploaded but showed "Page not found".

I guess I have to add something to the function file, or is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What your asking is really quite simple, but you need to take your time to read about creating new page templates for WordPress.

Take a look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates).

You need to create a custom loop that shows your desired posts preferably with [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for best practice.